# Trouble scanning a Data Lake Gen 2 source in Purview

Tags: azure-purview

I am using Azure Purview. I created an Azure Data Lake resource. I am trying to scan the source. When I try to scan the source the connection fails as can be seen from the image below:

[image]

I did try to use this link to figure out how to solve this:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/purview/manage-credentials?wt.mc_id=mspurview_inproduct_scan_msiauth_csadai

But I haven't been able to. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to copy the 'Managed Identity Name' for the Purview account and add it a role assignment of 'Storage Blob Data Reader' for the ADLS Gen 2 Account. Here is a more detailed breakdown.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/565738/error-3835-purview-failed-to-access-the-adls-gen2.html